# Check box checking issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have an issue in checkbox checking in my data table.
The paginated checkboxes are not checked. My code is:

```
// Handle click on "Select all" control
$('#example-select-all').on('click', function(){
    // Check/uncheck all checkboxes in the table
    var rows = candidateTable.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
    console.log(rows);
    $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Can you add a sample fiddle

Comment: Did you try: ` $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));`

Comment: @Phong thank you for your response. I add the given code. But its working same as previous

Comment: Give me your sample HTML please.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<table id="candidates-table" class="display compact nowrap" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="1" id="example-select-all"></th>
                                    <th>Firstname</th>
                                    <th>Lastname</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Drive</th>
                                    <th>Department</th>
                                    <th>Experience</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
```

js:

```
 var candidateTable = $('#candidates-table').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
       { width: '10%', targets: -1,  }
    ],
    "stateSave": true,
    "responsive" : true,
    "processing": false,
    "deferRender": true,
    "order": [[3,"disabled"]],
    "ajax": {
        "url": baseUrl + "admin/candidates",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },

    'fnCreatedRow': function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        $(nRow).attr('id', 'candidate-' + aData.id);
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "render": function (data, type, content, meta) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + content.id + '">';

            }
    },
      {
            "render": function (data, type, content, meta) {
                return content.firstname;

            }
    },


    ]
});

 // Handle click on "Select all" control
$('#example-select-all').on('click', function(){
    // Get all rows with search applied
    var rows = candidateTable.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
    // Check/uncheck checkboxes for all rows in the table
    $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```